# How to include the value of a clicked button in a separate form with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm using ui-router to display two views on a page with AngularJS. The bottom view is a list of products to choose from. The top view on the page is a form that displays for the user to complete after each item is selected. I would like the form to include the value of the selected item when it is ultimately submitted. The two views currently use separate controllers.

It is my understanding that AngularJS doesn't use hidden fields. What's the best way to associate the form with the selected item so that it will be included when it is submitted? Ideally, I would like to bind the selection type to the form as soon as the user clicks the "select" button.

HTML:

```
<!--Form HTML-->

<form name="myForm">
<div class="control-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="editProject.project.name">
</div>
   <label>Special instructions for this item</label>
   <textarea name="description" ng-model="editProject.project.description"></textarea>
<a href="#/" class="btn">Cancel</a>
<button ng-click="editProject.save()">Save</button>
</form>


<!--HTML for List of Items to Select-->

<tr ng-repeat="selection in selectionList.selections">
    <td>{{selection.type}}</td>
    <td>{{selection.cost}}</td>
    <td><button ng-click="(selection.type)">Select</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Controllers:

```
//controller for form

myApp.controller('NewProjectCtrl', function($location, $timeout, Projects) {
var editProject = this;
editProject.save = function() {
    Projects.$add(editProject.project).then(function(data) {
        $location.path('/');
    });
};


//controller for list of items to select from

myApp.controller('SelectionListCtrl', function(Selections) {
var selectionList = this;
selectionList.selections = Selections;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think about it this way: Create a service and register it to myApp and here you store the data that's shared between these two controllers. When you select an item, you register its value in the service.

then you broadcast the change of the item in SelectionListCtrl: `$scope.$broadcast("new Item was selected")`

Then, in the NewProjectCtrl, you should listen to this "new Item was selected" `$scope.$on("new Item was selected")` and here you can fetch the value from the shared service and display or do whatever you want with it in the view

Answer (score 0):

Like Feras said you can use service for setting and getting a value from two different forms.

my factory for setting and getting a value

```
app.factory('MainService', function() {
  var itemProd = [];
  return {
    setProd: function(item) {
      itemProd.push(item);
      console.log(itemProd);
    },
    getProd: function() {
      return itemProd;
    }
  }
});
```

if you need the full code here is my fiddle "http://plnkr.co/edit/hvxI2ABmMBR6bNyKViFC?p=preview"

Comment: Thank you. I'm having trouble getting your plunker to work, though.